# How to implement a self-referenced relation in Sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a blog where I can create posts. These posts can be of several languages : English, Spanish, French.

Each ticket I'm gonna create will be translated. I would like each post to be linked in db to other posts in other languages.

I saw that I could [self-reference](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/advanced-many-to-many/#self-references) on Sequelize but I couldn't make it work with this example. I can't find how I can implement it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to create the migration files to make it work completely. It seems, if you don't use the sync() method from Sequelize, these junction tables are never created.

From the example of the Sequelize doc :

```
Person.belongsToMany(Person, { as: 'Children', through: 'PersonChildren' })
```

It goes like that for the posts :

- The model file :

`Post.belongsToMany(Post, { as: "Sibling", through: "PostSiblings" });`

- The Association table migration file

```js
    module.exports = {
      async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        await queryInterface.createTable("PostSiblings", {
          id: {
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          },
          postId: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            references: {
              model: "Posts",
              key: "id",
            },
          },
          siblingId: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            references: {
              model: "Posts",
              key: "id",
            },
          },
          createdAt: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
          },
          updatedAt: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
          },
        });
      },
      async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        await queryInterface.dropTable("PostSiblings");
      },
    };
```

- I added some Seeds if you want to try:

```js
    
    module.exports = {
      up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.bulkInsert(
          "PostSiblings",
          [
            {
              postId: 1,
              siblingId: 1,
              createdAt: new Date(),
              updatedAt: new Date(),
            },
            {
              postId: 1,
              siblingId: 2,
              createdAt: new Date(),
              updatedAt: new Date(),
            },
          ],
          {}
        );
        /**
         * Add seed commands here.
         *
         * Example:
         * await queryInterface.bulkInsert('People', [{
         *   name: 'John Doe',
         *   isBetaMember: false
         * }], {});
         */
      },
    
      down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.bulkDelete("PostSiblings", null, {});
        /**
         * Add commands to revert seed here.
         *
         * Example:
         * await queryInterface.bulkDelete('People', null, {});
         */
      },
    };
```

And then, just

```js
const post = await db.Post.findOne({
          where: {
            title: req.params.title,
          },
          include: {
            model: db.Post,
            as: "Sibling",
          },
        });
```

The `through` property in the model references the table name, hence the plural word used.